# How can I find a property of a mongoose model by another property?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema as below:

```
     var personnelSchema = new Schema({

        fullName: String,
        dob: String,
        cNumber: String,
        address: String,
        wCard: String,
        dLic: Number,
        hrate: Number,

});
```

How can i find the property "hrate" by having only "fullName". I don't have access to ID otherwise I would find it by id.

Comment: `db.collection.find({ fullName: "your_string" })`

Answer (score 0):

You can see the mongoDB docs on `find` here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

On mongoose here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html/

But finding documents by field is usually done via:

```
Model.findOne({ fullName: 'someName'}, function (err, doc){
  // doc is a Document
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to `hrate` from `fullname` property then you can use `projection`.

> Use `find` for fetch all record and `findOne` for first match record.

```
  var projection = 'hrate' 

  UserModel.findOne({
    fullName: "Some String"
  }, projection, function (err, data) {
    if (!data) {
      callback('No data found', null)
    } else {
      callback(err, data)
    }
})



// Query would be in MongoDB shell:

> db.getCollection('test').findOne({fullName : "Hardik Shah"}, {'hrate' : 1})
```

If you want full document along with `hrate` then don't use `projection`

```
  UserModel.findOne({
    fullName: "Some String"
  }, function (err, data) {
    if (!data) {
      callback('No data found', null)
    } else {
      callback(err, data)
    }
})



// Query would be in MongoDB shell:

> db.getCollection('test').findOne({fullName : "Hardik Shah"})
```